# Matlab: Add thin line to image, saving results in thick lines

Tags: image, matlab, save, resolution

I am pretty annoyed by my problem here and couldn't really find anything useful.
The problem is, I have huge images (we're talking about 4000*5000 pixels) where I detect objects and add bounding boxes as well as some thin lines. So far, so good. Now I want to accurately analyze many of those images in parallel, where the MATLAB figure window is just too slow. Thus, I want to save those images. What happens then, is that the thin lines in the MATLAB figure window become thicker making the graphics file more or less useless.
Here's the code:

```
img = imread('blabla.jpg');
polyfig = figure, imagesc(img);
axis off
axis image
hold on

for i=1:nl
    line([xmin xmax],[lines(1,i) lines(1,i)],'Color','r', 'LineWidth', 1);
end
```

This results in the nice figure, where, when zooming in, the lines are very very thin as I want them to be. Now I want to save those images:

```
set(polyfig,'PaperUnits','centimeters','PaperPosition',[0 0 100 100])
outfile = sprintf('/folders/result_poly_%s.eps', img_name(1:end-4));
print('-deps', outfile, '-r400');
```

I tried tons of different options when saving, but never getting the results I want to. Here are two examples:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW57B.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYEBD.jpg

I really don't know where I could change something to get what I want to get. Maybe you have a hint for me? I'd greatly appreciate that!

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the image from the figure with :

```
h = figure(1); imshow(Img);
saveas(h,'SavePath');
```